# Adobe AIR and Appcelerator Titanium for desktop application

Tags: air, titanium

Which would be better (performance and development time) for me if I'm creating an desktop application using HTML/CSS/JS?

Is AIR more efficient at Flex and ActionScript than HTML/JS?

I've played with Titanium for a bit, but packaged app is more than 30MB, which is more than the AIR runtime + app. Is it alway that big or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium ships with the entire runtime, adobe air does not. A person doesn't need "Titanium Desktop" installed to run your application.

I prefer titanium over adobe air, even though adobe air may be mature software for the following reasons:

It seems a restrictive, sandboxes and such.

It does not have bleeding edge web technologies, it seems as though adobe air hasn't updated their webkit even since the last version.

It does not require a user to install another application to get an application.

- actually it depends on how you bundle your titanium app as well (network install?)